# Regexp : How can I match function calling and the comments above it

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

```
#hello world calling

hello_world();

============================
//hello world calling

hello_world('hello');
==========================
/*
    Hello World Calling
    multiline comment
*/

hello_world('hello','world');
```

How can I match all 3 sections with different comment style along with function being called.

Along with that I want to capture comments as well as the arguments of the function . example

```
array(
    array(
        [0] => 'hello world calling';
        [1] => 'hello world calling';
        [2] => 'hello world calling multiline comment';
    )
    array(
        [0] => '';
        [1] => 'hello';
        [2] => 'hello world';
    )
)
```

Tried some regex but didnt got what I wanted

Comment: nothing to show anything substantial :( . was going with hit and trail . `(#|//+|/\*)+([\s\S])+`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114104/matching-all-three-kinds-of-php-comments-with-regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/zN9gT9/1):

```
(?:(?:#|\/\/)(.*?)|\/\*((?:.|\n)*?)\*\/)*\n*?\b(.*?)\((.*?)\);
```

Comment: wow this works ! however doesnt matches functions if they dont have comments above it

Comment: @user2947180 updated. It should now also match method calls without comments before.

Comment: great stuff ! how can I use it to match only one function example `hello_world` ?

Comment: @user2947180 To only match function calls where function name is `hello_world` you can try `(?:(?:#|\/\/)(.*?)|\/\*((?:.|\n)*?)\*\/)*\n*?\b(hello_world)\((.*?)\);`. Can see it here: https://regex101.com/r/rQ5kI9/1

Answer (score 0):

I tested your text on https://regex101.com/#pcre and these are the closest that I came up with.

For commets:

```
/\#(.*)|\/\/(.*)|\/\*([\w\W]*)\*\//g
```

The result:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [1-20]  `hello world calling`
MATCH 2
2.  [69-88] `hello world calling`
MATCH 3
3.  [141-188]   `
    Hello World Calling
    multiline comment
`
```

For arguments:

```
/\((.*)\)/g
```

The result:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [34-34] ``
MATCH 2
1.  [102-109]   `'hello'`
MATCH 3
1.  [204-219]   `'hello','world'`
```